# jQuery mask não lê innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masked-input

Estou com problemas em gerar a leitura da máscara(jQuery) em elementos gerados via `innerHTML`. Só que o `validator` funciona e após tentar inserir um dado fora da máscara ele carrega a página com a máscara.

Aqui a mask:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready( function() {     
     $.validator.addMethod("conceito", function (value, element) { 
     return ((/^((((([1]{1}[0]{1})\,([0]{1}))|((([0]{1})(\d){1}))\,(\d){1}))|([F]{1}))?$/i.test(value))); 
      }, "Digite uma m&eacute;dia v&aacute;lida (valores entre 00,0 e 10,0 ou o conceito F)"); 

      $('.conceito').mask("A9,9"); 
      $('#gerar_conceitos').validate({ 
        // Define as regras 
        errorElement: "em", 
        errorContainer: $(".error"), 
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
          element.parent().append(error); 
        }, 
        success: function(label) { 
          label.text("Sem erros."); 
        }, 
        messages: { 
          conceito: { 
            required: "Digite uma média v&aacute;lida (valores entre 00,0 e 10,0)" 
          } 
        } 
      }); 

});   
</script>
```

E o innerHTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">            
 function msalterar(numerodematricula,conceito){
        c=document.getElementById('conceito['+numerodematricula+']');
        inner ="<label>M&eacute;dia:/label>";                       
                    inner += "<input type=\"text\" size \"4\" class=\"conceito\" name=\"conceito["+numerodematricula+"]\" value=\""+conceito+"\">";
                    c.innerHTML = inner;
                    dfinalizar();
            }

  </script>
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem a pergunta mas uma observação: o input que você está criando dinamicamente precisa receber a mascara de novo. A mascara inicialmente so está aplicada a elementos que já vieram no carregamento da página.

Comment: Exato Joao Paulo.

Comment: Exato, então você já fez isso e o erro continua? Se puder veja no Console do navegador(F12) se acusa algum erro de javascript.

Comment: Exato ele vem sem a máscara mas quando tento enviar um dado que não tem a máscara ele reseta a página e lê a máscara mas tenho que forçar o envio de algo errado para isso acontecer.

Comment: Tenta colocar $('.conceito').mask("A9,9"); entre a linha> c.innerHTML = inner; e a linha dfinalizar();

Answer (score 1):

Não estou vendo em que lugar você utiliza a function `msalterar()` e também não sei o que faz a function `dfinalizar()` mas imagino que após você gerar dinamicamente um `input`, você **deve aplicar novamente a `mask`**. Portanto experimente isso ou algo parecido:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">            
        function msalterar(numerodematricula,conceito){
            c=document.getElementById('conceito['+numerodematricula+']');
            inner ="<label>M&eacute;dia:/label>";                       
                    inner += "<input type=\"text\" size \"4\" class=\"conceito\" name=\"conceito["+numerodematricula+"]\" value=\""+conceito+"\">";
                    c.innerHTML = inner;
                    dfinalizar();

                     $('.conceito').mask("A9,9");
            }
  </script>
```